# PHP: Só percorre corretamente o FOREACH caso as checkbox sejam todas selecionadas

Tags: php

estou fazendo um trabalho e preciso entender o porque meu foreach só é percorrido para fazer o que desejo quando as checkbox são selecionadas em ordem:

```
<?php require_once("cabecalho.php"); 

$questao = new Questao ();
$QuestaoDAO = new QuestaoDAO($conexao);
$conteudoDAO = new ConteudoDAO($conexao);

$conteudo_fkid = $questao->getConteudo_fkid();
$chaveAvaliacao = $_POST['chaveAvaliacao'];

//echo $nomeConteudo;
?>  

<h1>Elaborar Avaliação</h1>

<form action="elaborarAvaliacao.php" method="post">
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="dynamic_field">
<tr>
    <td colspan="3"><center>Selecione os conteúdos referente a avaliação de chave: <b><?php echo $_SESSION['chaveAvaliacao']; ?></b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><b>Selecione contúdos: </b> </td>
    <td><b>Contúdos: </b> </td>
    <td><b>Qntd. de questão por conteúdo: </b> </td>
</tr>
<?php 
foreach($conteudoDAO->listaNomeConteudo() as $tipo) : 
    if ($tipo['id'] != 1){
?>
<tr>
    <td width ='175'><center><input type="checkbox" name="conteudosCheckbox[]" value="<?=$tipo['id']?>"> </td>
    <td><center><?=$tipo['nomeConteudo'];?></center></td>
    <td width ='275'><input class="form-control" type="number" name="qntdQuestaoPorConteudo_php[]"> </td>
</tr>

<?php 
}
endforeach  
?>

</table>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Criar</button>
</form>

<?php require_once("rodape.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("script.php"); ?>

---

    <?php require_once("cabecalho.php"); 
$chaveAvaliacao = $_SESSION['chaveAvaliacao'];

$conteudosCheckbox = $_POST['conteudosCheckbox'];
var_dump($conteudosCheckbox);
$contador = count($conteudosCheckbox);
$qntdQuestaoPorConteudo_php = $_POST['qntdQuestaoPorConteudo_php'];
var_dump($qntdQuestaoPorConteudo_php);
//$qntdQuestaoPorConteudo_php2 = $_POST['qntdQuestaoPorConteudo_php'];

$questaoDAO = new QuestaoDAO($conexao);
$conteudoDAO = new conteudoDAO($conexao);
$questao = new Questao();
$avaliacao = new Avaliacao;
$avaliacaoDAO = new AvaliacaoDAO($conexao);
$validador = 0;

$i=0;
//echo $conteudosCheckbox[0];
echo "foreach I:<br>";
foreach ($conteudosCheckbox as $conteudo) :
    echo "<br>PASSADA DO I : " . $i . "<br>";
    $qntdQuestaoPorConteudo_banco = $questaoDAO->listaContadorQuestao($conteudo);
    //echo $i."<br>";
    //echo "qntdQuestao pode : " . $quantidadeQuestao . "<br>";
    echo "qntdQuestaoPorConteudo_banco: " . $qntdQuestaoPorConteudo_banco;
    echo "<br> qntdQuestaoPorConteudo_php: " . $qntdQuestaoPorConteudo_php[$i] . "<br>"; 
    if ($qntdQuestaoPorConteudo_banco < $qntdQuestaoPorConteudo_php[$i]) {
        echo $i;
        echo "<br>";
        echo "banco: " . $qntdQuestaoPorConteudo_banco;
        echo "<br>";
        echo "php: " .  $qntdQuestaoPorConteudo_php[$i];
        echo "<br>";
    /*  echo "Não há questões suficientes cadastradas para o conteúdo: <b>" . $conteudoDAO->listaConteudoEspecifico($conteudo) . 
        "<br></b> Cadastre novas questões para o conteúdo e tente novamente. <br><br>";*/
        $avaliacaoDAO->removeAvaliacao($chaveAvaliacao);
        $validador = 1;
    }
$i++;
endforeach;

if ($validador == 1) {
    echo "O que deseja fazer? <br><br>";
    ?>
    <form action="index.php" method="POST">
        <input type="submit" value="Inicio" class="btn btn-danger">  
    </form>

    <form action="formularioQuestao.php" method="POST">
        <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar questão" class="btn btn-success">  
    </form>

    <form action="formularioChaveAvaliacao.php">
        <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar nova avaliação" class="btn btn-warning">  
    </form>
    <?php
}
else {

$j = 0;    echo "<br>";

echo "foreach J:";

foreach ($conteudosCheckbox as $conteudo) :
    echo "<br>";

    //echo "entra no foreach?";
    $quantidadeQuestao = $questaoDAO->listaContadorQuestao($conteudo);
    $questoesBanco = $questoesBanco + $quantidadeQuestao;

    $avaliacao->setChaveAvaliacao($chaveAvaliacao);
    $avaliacao_fkid = $avaliacaoDAO->selecionaAvaliacao($avaliacao->getChaveAvaliacao());
//   $conteudo_fkid = $questaoDAO->selectConteudo_fkid($conteudo);
// echo "<br>CONTEUDO FKID : " . $conteudo_fkid . "<br>";
    echo "<br>";
    $questao = $questaoDAO->listaQuestaoConteudo_fkid($conteudo);
// echo "<br>lista questao conteudo fkid: " . $questao . "<br><br>";
$contadorWhile = 0;
//echo "<br>qntdQuestaoPorConteudo_php: " . $qntdQuestaoPorConteudo_php[$j] . "<br>";
echo "<br>";
    while ($qntdQuestaoPorConteudo_php[$j] > $contadorWhile) {
        $ids = array();
        foreach($questao as $questao_id) :
            $ids[] = $questao_id->getId();
        endforeach; 
        $rand = array_rand($ids);
        // $conteudo_fkid->getConteudo_fkid();
    $avaliacaoDAO->insereAvaliacao_questoes($avaliacao_fkid, $ids[$rand], $conteudo);
    $contadorWhile++;
    echo "qntd passadas (numero questao) : " . $j . "<br>";
};
    //var_dump($questao);
    //echo "questao " . $questao[$j];
    // echo $avaliacao_fkid . "<br>";
    $j++;
endforeach;
/*
echo "<br> -----------------------------------------------------<br>";
$array = $avaliacaoDAO->listaAvaliacao();
foreach ($array as $a):
echo $a['chaveAvaliacao'] . "<br>";
endforeach;
*/
}
require_once("rodape.php"); 
require_once("script.php");
```

Comment: Simplesmente pq só são enviadas as checkboxes clicadas. Tem vários posts falando disto no site, O que você precisa é dar um nome unico para cada checkbox e verificar junto de outra referência. Por exemplo, `conteudosCheckbox[$id]` ou por o ID no value (não o tipo, só o ID)

Comment: Verifique os links do quadro acima, caso ainda tenha dúvidas, avise.